# jquery: select and deselect all checkbox link works only once

Tags: jquery, html, select, checked

Morning you all,
I woke up to a different kind of problem i didn't expect to find.

so I have a group of check boxes that can be all checked or unchecked by two dedicated links. here is the HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Reasons to be happy</legend>
    <a class="selectAll" href="#">Select All</a>
    <a class="deselectAll" href="#">Deselect All</a>
        <input name="reasons" id="iwokeup" type="checkbox" value="iwokeup" />
    <label for="iwokeup">I woke up</label>
        <input name="reasons" id="health" type="checkbox" value="health" />
    <label for="health">My health</label>
        <input name="reasons" id="family" type="checkbox" value="family" />
    <label for="family">My family</label>
        <input name="reasons" id="sunshine" type="checkbox" value="sunshine" />
    <label for="sunshine">The sun is shining</label>
</fieldset>
```

Here is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('fieldset').on("click","a.selectAll",function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).nextAll('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',true);

    });

    $('fieldset').on("click","a.deselectAll",function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).nextAll('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
    });
});
```

Problem is that they both work only once. like if i select/deselect the first time it works then it doesn't after. What could be the issue?

OH, im in Nairobi Kenya, that could explain the morning part :)

Comment: Works for me in Fiddle.

Comment: give a class to every checkbox and use that to select or unselect . you will have a less complex and less lines of code.

Comment: @John Kariuki you code works fine here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CSpdX/)

Answer (score 2):

Use prop instead of attr as prop is recomended for bool, and attr gives the inconsistent behaviour for jQuery version 1.9 +

```
$(this).nextAll('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
```

To see what difference attr and prop have I made a demo

Using attr, work only once! click Check button then Uncheck and thats it now Check wont work, [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LG8Mf/)

```
$('#btnChk').click(function(){
    $('#chk1').attr('checked', true);
});
$('#btnUnchk').click(function(){
    $('#chk1').attr('checked', false);
});
```

Using prop, **works always** [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LG8Mf/1/)

```
$('#btnChk').click(function(){
    $('#chk1').prop('checked', true);
});
$('#btnUnchk').click(function(){
    $('#chk1').prop('checked', false);
});
```

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.
>
> For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType,
>   ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved
>   and set with the .prop() method. Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties
>   were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the
>   scope of attr. These do not have corresponding attributes and are only
>   properties, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: i did not dw.. But why did .attr() wont work here..?

Comment: I experience similar behavior with attr

Comment: how different is prop from attr?

Comment: @JohnKariuki, I have added more description. Please check the updated answer.